# How to get cell ID of ASP.NET GridView in jQuery on right Click?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView in my Application. I need to provide user some functionality to edit some cells or delete rows. I need to show context menu when user right clicks on some cell. When user click "Edit" I need to show some help Info and put this cell in Edit mode and set focus on It. Here is my Code:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#myMenu").hide();
            $("#helpRow").hide();
            $("table[id$='gvListOfMatters'] > tbody > tr > td").bind('contextmenu', function (e) {
            $("#myMenu").hide();
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).css("cursor", "pointer");
            iColIndex = $(this).closest("tr td").prevAll("tr td").length;
            iRowIndex = $(this).closest("tr").prevAll("tr").length;
            rowid = $(this).parent().children()[0].innerHTML;
            if (!isNaN(rowid)) {
                //call context menu here
                $("#myMenu").css({
                    top: e.pageY + "px",
                    left: e.pageX + "px",
                    position: 'absolute'
                });
                $("#myMenu").show(100);
            }
        });
        });
        //hide when left mouse is clicked
        $(document).bind('click', function (e) {
            $("#myMenu").hide(100);
        });

        var rowid = 0;
        function fnEdit() {
            var lnkEdit = document.getElementById('<%=lnkEdit.ClientID %>');
            var hiddenField = document.getElementById('<%=fldRowID.ClientID %>');
            hiddenField.value = rowid;
            lnkEdit.click();
        };

        function fnDelete() {
            var lnkDelete = document.getElementById('<%=lnkDelete.ClientID %>');
            var hiddenField = document.getElementById('<%=fldRowID.ClientID %>');
            hiddenField.value = rowid;
            lnkDelete.click();
        };
    </script>

    <div id="helpRow">
    </div>
    <asp:GridView ID="gvHelpRow" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" CssClass="helpRow" ShowHeader="false" Visible="false"></asp:GridView>
    <br />

    <div id="SourceGrid" class="table responsive">
        <asp:GridView ID="gvListOfMatters" runat="server"
        SOME Tamplate COLUMNS…
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>

    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEdit" runat="server" Style="display: none" OnClick="lnkEdit_Click" />
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" runat="server" Style="display: none" OnClick="lnkDelete_Click" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="fldRowID" runat="server" />

    <%--↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓ContextMenu↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓--%>
    <div id="myMenu" class="contextMenu">
        <table style='width: 100%;'>
            <tr>
                <td onclick="fnEdit();">- Edit
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td onclick="fnDelete();">- Delete
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <%--↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑ContextMenu↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑↑--%>

</asp:Content>
```

First question is how to get ID of selected cell? I mentioned place where is the problem in my code.

I have event handlers for edit.click() and delete.click() in code-behind. In edit.click() I'm binding a data source to a helpRow GridView.

My second Question is how to show this HelpRow GridView right under the row that was clicked? I can't find the way how to set right position for this grid... I know that it should be absolute position and X and Y position...

So the whole Idea:
User right clicks on some cell. I need to show context menu ("Edit" and "Delete") and at this moment store rowID and cellID (rowid i got, but cellid is the problem...). When user clicks edit, I need to bind some data (it's stores in Session) based on rowid to helpRow Grid View. Then I need to show this helRow right under selected row (Position: absolute and ... HOW TO GET RIGHT POSITION???) and make selected cell in edit mode and set focus to this cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own way! 
First of all I bind function to the `td` instead of `tr`

```
$("table[id$='gvListOfMatters'] > tbody > tr > td").bind('contextmenu', function (e) {
                $("#myMenu").hide();
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).css("cursor", "pointer");
                iColIndex = $(this).closest("tr td").prevAll("tr td").length;
                iRowIndex = $(this).closest("tr").prevAll("tr").length;
                rowid = $(this).parent().children()[0].innerHTML;
                if (!isNaN(rowid)) {
                    //call context menu here
                    $("#myMenu").css({
                        top: e.pageY + "px",
                        left: e.pageX + "px",
                        position: 'absolute'
                    });
                    $("#myMenu").show(100);
                }
            });
```

Now I can get rowID, cellID, and all text inside every cell in this row.
I will update my original question with the latest update